# Разница между `int()` и `int (*)()` в параметре функции

Tags: c++, функции, указатели

В чем разница между:

```
int fun(int ()) {
    return 1;
}
```

и

```
int fun(int (*)()) {
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: ни в чем - это одинаковые сигнатуры

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Вы можете сами проверить есть ли разница и в чем она заключается с помощью: компилятора и `nm`. При попытке скомпилировать программу (или либу) с обоими определениями в одном `namespace` вам выдаст ошибку о повторном определении функции. Если же скомпилировать сначала с первым, а потом со вторым вариантом и посмотреть что в итоге получилось с помощью `nm`, то вы увидете такую картину (без манглинга):

```
0000000000004028 B __bss_start
0000000000004028 b completed.7325
                 w __cxa_finalize@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000004018 D __data_start
0000000000004018 W data_start
0000000000001070 t deregister_tm_clones
00000000000010e0 t __do_global_dtors_aux
0000000000003df0 t __do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry
0000000000004020 D __dso_handle
0000000000003df8 d _DYNAMIC
0000000000004028 D _edata
0000000000004030 B _end
00000000000011a4 T _fini
0000000000001120 t frame_dummy
0000000000003de8 t __frame_dummy_init_array_entry
000000000000216c r __FRAME_END__
0000000000004000 d _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 w __gmon_start__
0000000000002004 r __GNU_EH_FRAME_HDR
0000000000001000 t _init
0000000000003df0 t __init_array_end
0000000000003de8 t __init_array_start
0000000000002000 R _IO_stdin_used
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
00000000000011a0 T __libc_csu_fini
0000000000001140 T __libc_csu_init
                 U __libc_start_main@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000001134 T main
00000000000010a0 t register_tm_clones
0000000000001040 T _start
0000000000004028 D __TMC_END__
0000000000001125 T fun(int (*)())
```

```
0000000000004028 B __bss_start
0000000000004028 b completed.7325
                 w __cxa_finalize@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000004018 D __data_start
0000000000004018 W data_start
0000000000001070 t deregister_tm_clones
00000000000010e0 t __do_global_dtors_aux
0000000000003df0 t __do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry
0000000000004020 D __dso_handle
0000000000003df8 d _DYNAMIC
0000000000004028 D _edata
0000000000004030 B _end
00000000000011a4 T _fini
0000000000001120 t frame_dummy
0000000000003de8 t __frame_dummy_init_array_entry
000000000000216c r __FRAME_END__
0000000000004000 d _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 w __gmon_start__
0000000000002004 r __GNU_EH_FRAME_HDR
0000000000001000 t _init
0000000000003df0 t __init_array_end
0000000000003de8 t __init_array_start
0000000000002000 R _IO_stdin_used
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
00000000000011a0 T __libc_csu_fini
0000000000001140 T __libc_csu_init
                 U __libc_start_main@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000001134 T main
00000000000010a0 t register_tm_clones
0000000000001040 T _start
0000000000004028 D __TMC_END__
0000000000001125 T fun(int (*)())
```

Тобишь первый вариант и второй - это просто два варианта одной записи

Answer (score 12):

При выведении типов параметров функции, любой функциональный тип заменяется на указатель на функцию. [[dcl.fct]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#5):

> [...] After determining the type of each parameter, any parameter of type “array of `T`” or of function type `T` is adjusted to be “pointer to `T`”. [...]

Поэтому тип `int ()` в параметре функции на самом деле обозначает тип `int (*)()`.

[Пример](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e56c26aa0feeef6d):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int f(int ptr())
{
    cout << "f: " << std::is_same<int (*)(), decltype(ptr)>::value << endl; //true
    return 0;
}

int g()
{
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "main: " << std::is_same<int (*)(), decltype(g)>::value << endl; //false
    f(nullptr);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

В аргументе функции - ничем. Но засада может быть, когда используется не в аргументе функции - https://godbolt.org/z/6xzzeW.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


using Callback1_t = int (double);
using Callback2_t = int (*)(double);


int func1(Callback1_t fn1)
{
    fn1(1.0);
    return 1;
}


int func2(Callback2_t fn2)
{
    func1(fn2);
    fn2(2.0);
    return 2;
}


class A {
    Callback1_t fn1_;
    Callback2_t fn2_;
public:
    A(Callback1_t fn1, Callback2_t fn2) : fn1_(fn1), fn2_(fn2) {}
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

```
<source>: In constructor 'A::A(int (*)(double), Callback2_t)':
<source>:29:43: error: class 'A' does not have any field named 'fn1_'
   29 |     A(Callback1_t fn1, Callback2_t fn2) : fn1_(fn1), fn2_(fn2) {}
      |                                           ^~~~
```

Comment: Второй параметр `main` нестандартный

Comment: Бойлеплейтный код код какой-то был.

Comment: Стоит исправить в любом случае